# If you make a game for facebook do you have to have a "real website" on the domain name?

Tags: browser-based-games, facebook

Can you just use the domain to house your database and code?  Do you have to have a "real" front end webpage?

Comment: Can you clarify "real website" vs the alternative?

Comment: I mean just use the domain that I have to hold the logic and database of the game.  But if people browse to it, they won't get a webpage.

Comment: Ah, so HTTP(S) service on port 80. I don't imagine that Facebook is checking for that.

Comment: I may not understand.  I thought that was what you were supposed to do.  I think I need to do more research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is "do you need a complete website with index page and links, or can you just host game.html". If I'm right the answer is: no you don't need a real website. Aslong as facebook can access the game, and it is playable you're fine.

I would not recommend it though, what if a player goes straight to that link in his browser (www.website.com/game.html) but isn't online on facebook, does that affect how the game plays?

Useable for minigames that don't need usernames though.

Comment: Overall this is correct, but I'm not in agreement with recommending against it. Perhaps other companies do it differently, but our games are only accessed through facebook (or kongregate, which is same-difference for this question) and not through a front-end on our website.